# Image files under src root folder not present in android build (Codename ONE)

Tags: android, image, file-io, build, codenameone

It is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996693/adding-image-in-java-code-in-code-name), however my problem is that the images are there in Codename ONE simulator (image can be loaded and shows correctly), but when I do an android build and try it on my phone, I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. According to the comment given by Shai Almog to the question mentioned above, it should work.

What is wrong here? Could it be filenames have to be all lower case or all upper case?

(I am omitting the source here because it seems to be a problem with packaging rather than the code itself.)

UPDATE: I tried changing all filenames to lowercase but to no avail.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Does this also apply to Codename ONE or just "normal" android development? There's nothing about an asset folder in the (Codename ONE-) docs...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out that you have to open the files as resources (Thanks to @ChrisStratton for pointing in the right direction whilst the comment was obviously about android SDK development).

This works:

```
private static Image loadImage(String path) throws IOException {
    InputStream in=null;
    try {
        // works in simulator but not on device:
        // in = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(path);

        // works on both simulator and device:
        in = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(null, path);
        return Image.createImage(in);
    } finally {
        if (in!=null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create Images with EncodedImage.create("/fileName") or better yet add them to the res file where you can use the multi image format: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---fetch-an-image-from-the-resource-file---add-a-multiimage.html

The approach with the input stream is slightly less efficient than what we can do internally.

Files in the src directory are implicitly placed in the assets directory for Android in Codename One so there is no need for an assets directory.